# php general to particular result

Tags: php, sql

```
require_once('server.php');
```

Just Call this Function with your username and password. this will give you your unread sms

```
$getData = getMsgs("myeis","badshaha");
```

`if($getData==-1)`enter code here die("Invalid Username/Password or Unable to connect Server

```
$data=json_decode($getData)
```

You can Retrieve Data by following Method:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)

     echo "<strong>Message</strong>: ".$data[$i]->msg.
     echo "<strong>Source</strong>: ".$data[$i]->src.
     echo "<strong>Date</strong>: ".$data[$i]->date
     //echo "<strong>Contact Name</strong>: ".$data[$i]->name
```

This is a general script  it will show the result as below

```
(first record)
message:xyz
source :xyz
date :xyz
contatct name:xyz

(second)
message:xyz
source :xyz
date :xyz
contatct name:xyz

(third)
message:xyz
source :xyz
date :xyz
contatct name:xyz

(fourth)
message:xyz
source :xyz
date :xyz
contatct name:xyz
.
.
.
```

up to all records

but i just wanna to get first record  or purticular record  how is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

$data[0] gives you access to the first message. make sure that there is actually at least 1 message, like sizeof($data) > 0

Comment: dear where to put $data[0]? i have tried but not working . i am new so please edit my script

Comment: Have a look at ankit's answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$data=json_decode($getData)
echo $data[0]->msg is a first record.so you can fetch any record by using constant number
```

Comment: thank you so musch problem solved  ........ i solute every coder ... please close my qustion